# how to find what processes have written to a file on Linux

Tags: linux, file

Is there a way to find out which process wrote to a give file earlier. I am having a problem where multiple processes seem to be writing to a file. I know one of the processes but not sure who else is writing to the file. I am on linux/ubuntu. Is there a way a log is mantained by the OS on what processes have written to a specified file

Comment: fuser has nto been useful as far as I can see since it tells the processes currently writing to the file

Comment: There is no such log by default on the system. You will probably have to create such a log yourself. See my proposed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Create a small monitoring process** which will log periodically who is currently accessing the file.

You can write a small script using fuser. Is here a quick example (to be improved)

```
#!/bin/bash

log=~/file-access.log

while true
do
  fuser your_file >> $log
  sleep 0.2s
done
```

But you will have to be lucky that the process writing to this file takes enough time to have the chance to detect it with fuser.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing by default to keep track of which processes wrote to a file after the fact.

If you can repro at will, inotify or similar can help you monitor who is writing to the file as it happens.